# Error at Gradle Update: Expected minSdkVersion >= 21 but found 1

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

My project was perfectly building and running yesterday. Now I updated Gradle since Android Studio offered me the option. Now it can not run my project. Every time I try, it prompts this error:

```
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.
    > Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug' property 'numberOfBuckets'.
    > Expected minSdkVersion >= 21 but found 1
```

I literally didn't change my project a single bit, and I'm a bit desperate. I don't understand the error, and there's no info on other posts. Please help me, thanks a lot.

My Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ecomove.iotdevice"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
    implementation files('libs\\slf4j-simple-1.7.30.jar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // api ('com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-device-client:1.29.4')
    // api ('com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.provisioning:provisioning-device-client:1.8.4')

    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-device-client:1.28.0'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-deps:0.11.0'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.provisioning:provisioning-device-client:1.8.4'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.provisioning.security:security-provider:1.4.0'

    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'
}
```

Comment: open your `implementation files('libs\\slf4j-simple-1.7.30.jar')` and check there manifest and `build.gradle` section

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had selected to create the android app using `Android 9.0 Pie` but at the time when I initially ran Android Studio only `Android 11.0 (R)` was installed on my development machine, so I clicked on `Tools->SDK Manager`,

[image]

Then in the `Settings for New Projects` I selected Android 9.0 Pie and clicked Apply:

[image]

After that I was able to debug without receiving the `minSdkVersion` error.

Answer (score 0):

I found this Bug and Realised my Running Device was set to one with a API level below 21, Make sure you test on a Device >= API Level 21

Comment: Its great that you say that, and its pretty clear with the error message but how do you do that!? that is how you would get credit for the answer, else u didnt help at all!!

Answer (score -1):

**try this**
change your OkHttp version

it's work for me

```
  implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.12"){
  force = true //API 19 support
  }
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.12'
```